# Lightning Ready for exisiting App Exchange application

Tags: lightning, force.com

I was wondering after we create a case with Salesforce for getting "lightning ready" badge for my existing App on AppExchange. Does it need to go through any Security review process ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Lightning Ready Requirements May 12 2017](https://org62.my.salesforce.com/sfc/p/#000000000062/a/30000000bwUm/Y6To9GKaWAJeRlbaUReGYz4FHR.xW6xLcwahCgIO7DI) still contain the process I used where my already security reviewed app was given its "Lightning Ready" badge based on my declaration via a case of having done the appropriate testing. I did **not** have to put the app through another security review pass.